# Use Font Awesome with react-native-elements

Tags: react-native, font-awesome, react-native-elements

I want to use `react-native-element` with a react native app. First, I installed the react-elements which was successful. Now I'm trying to use an `Icon` with the type as `font-awesome`. But icons are not displaying properly. Should I need to separately install font-awesome as well in order to get the icons working? Or am I missing something here. Here is my code,

```
<Icon
    raised
    name='heartbeat'
    type='font-awesome'
    color='#f50'
    onPress={() => console.log('hello')} />
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you post the logs? if the icons are not displaying there should be a warning or error printed.

Comment: Nope nothing printed on console as errors or warnings. It just displays crossed placeholder instead the icon.

Comment: Did you try different icon names? try "heartbeat" as they are using it in the official documentation. https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/icon.html

Comment: Actually I tried that originally exactly as in the documentation. Should I need to install font-awesome separately?

Comment: Just to be sure: Icons from other sets, like `material` or `ionicon` do show up properly?

Comment: I don't' think so as they didn't mention that in the documentation. For me, I am using    `react-native-vector-icons` and I used a lot of icons from font-awesome without installing font-awesome.

Comment: @Maximilian: I tried with material icons. Still the same.

Comment: One more follow-up: Are other elements from the react-native-elements package working, like [Badge](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/badge.html)? And are you using Expo or pure react-native?

Comment: I'm using pure react-native with typescript. Yeah Badge, Button, Input all working fine. It just icons are not rendered properly. One more thing, I had to install react-native-vector-icons separately after installing react-native-elements that I'm not supposed to do. Without that it was giving an build error.

Comment: Okay, I just wanted to say you'll need to install react-native-vector-icons after react-native-elements manually if not using Expo. You are supposed to do that actually according to the [docs (React Native CLI)](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/getting_started.html). I would double-check if react-native-vector-icons is indeed installed. Otherwise I'm currently out of ideas, I'm trying to reproduce this right now.

Comment: Thanks mate for taking your time. I would just reinstall it just in case.

Comment: I just tried with a clean project. Installed react-native-elements, then react-native-vector-icons. Then linked it using `react-native link react-native-vector-icons`. Worked for me. If it still won't work for you, it'd probably be best to unlink it, remove the node_modules folder and reinstall everything through `npm i`.

Comment: Ops, I didn't link it as you have done `react-native link react-native-vector-icons`. Probably that might be the issue. Let me do it see.

Comment: @MaximilianKrause: Its working! Thanks mate. Please post it as an Answer - so that I can mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`react-native-elements` requires the `react-native-vector-icons` to be installed manually if you're not using Expo or create-react-native-app. [See the documentation (React Native CLI) for more info.](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/getting_started.html)

After you've installed both packages, you need to link `react-native-vector-icons` (as you can see in the [README of the GitHub repo](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/)). The easiest method to do so is by doing this:

```
react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```

Afterwards, everything should work. If you've already done all of this and it's still not working, please delete the `node_modules` folder and reinstall your node packages by using `npm i`. If it's still not working, try to manually link the package (you can find a guide on how to do so on the GitHub repo linked above).